# QEMU fpu mode error when attempting to run MIPS binary

Tags: reverse-engineering, qemu, firmware

I have unpacked a firmware binary using binwalk and have identified the architecture as MIPS by running *file bin/busybox* . When I try to run the binary with the proper static version of qemu, i get an error with FPU mode ex:

```
 chroot . ./qemu-mips-static bin/busybox
 qemu: Unexpected FPU mode
```

I can't find anything on this error.  I have tried this on several different firmwares and i keep getting the same error.

The OS is Kali linux with qemu-user-static installed and the qemu-mips-static static binary place in the root directory of the unpacked firmware.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I have put it off.  I tentatively believe it's a bad patch, but I know there must be some reason for this patch.  Code can be compiled with soft fpu or hard fpu instructions and work fine with a cpu w/o an FPU, but in the later case fpu emulation needs to be built into the kernel.  Hopefully I'll know more soon.

Answer (score 0):

QEMU is complaining because the ELF file specifies a floating point ABI that this QEMU can't handle. I would start by checking whether you have the correct QEMU binary. For MIPS there are qemu-mips-static, qemu-mips64-static, qemu-mips64el-static, qemu-mipsel-static, qemu-mipsn32-static and qemu-mipsn32el-static. Which one you want depends on whether your binary is 32 or 64 bit, whether it is big or little endian, and whether it is using the "n32" ABI or not. You may also need to pass QEMU the correct -cpu argument to tell it to emulate the CPU that the binary was built for.

Comment: I am certain that I am using the correct version MIPS binary. I have tried all of the different cpu types (available via -cpu help).  I can't find a way to specify n32 ABI.

Comment: You specify the n32 ABI by using qemu-mipsn32-static instead of qemu-mips-static, I think.

Comment: Thanks! per your advice I have tried all mips and mipsn32 static binaries with all available cpu and no luck.

Comment: @PeterMaydell The name of the executable varies by distro.  On Gentoo the -static is omitted and instead all qemu executables for running a whole system are named qemu-system-<arch>.

Comment: qemu-system-<arch> is the usual name for the system emulators, yes. This question isn't about those, it's about the linux-user emulators (which might be qemu-<arch> or qemu-<arch>-static).

Comment: @PeterMaydell Yes, I know.  I was just trying to clarify that point as a lot of online instructions don't account for that difference.  I've solved the stupid problem!  So I'm happy now. :)  This has been a thorn in my side for a few months and I've kept ignoring it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1825002) introduced in 3.1.0.  I have posted a [patch here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/419651860/0001-1825002-fix-mips-Unexpected-FPU-mode.patch).

As a partial work-around, you can try launching the program via `/lib/ld-*.so` -- this works for me in some cases, but it does not recurse, so if you launch /bin/bash then, anything it attempts to launch (that's foreign) will fail.  e.g.,

```
chroot mychroot /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel /lib/ld-2.19.so /bin/bash`
```

You can also go back to 3.0.0 or 2.12.1.  If you're using Gentoo, they have been removed due to CVEs where they opted to remove all previous versions rather than patch them.

This occurs when the ELF's program header does not contain an entry of type 0x70000003 (PT_MIPS_ABIFLAGS) -- this isn't required, but when absent qemu is using an uninitialized value for the FPU mode and blowing up.